# How to delete post thumbnails in index page? (twenty fourteen theme)

Tags: thumbnails, theme-twenty-fourteen

i want to delete post thumbnails in index page. but online top of the posts. i don't want to delete "featured-content" part. how can i do this?

i tried replace the main loop with this:

```
while (have_posts()) :
         the_post();
         echo "<a href='.the_permalink().'>".the_title()."</a>";
         the_content();
   endwhile;
```

but now, my css doesn't work with that code.

*sorry about my english.*

here is my new content.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The default template for displaying content
 *
 * Used for both single and index/archive/search.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<?php if ( ! is_home() ) twentyfourteen_post_thumbnail(); ?>    
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php if ( in_array( 'category', get_object_taxonomies( get_post_type() ) ) && twentyfourteen_categorized_blog() ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-meta">
            <span class="cat-links"><?php echo get_the_category_list( _x( ', ', 'Used between list items, there is a space after the comma.', 'twentyfourteen' ) ); ?></span>
        </div>
        <?php
            endif;

            if ( is_single() ) :
                the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
            else :
                the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>' );
            endif;
        ?>

        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php
                if ( 'post' == get_post_type() )
                    twentyfourteen_posted_on();

                if ( ! post_password_required() && ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) ) :
            ?>
            <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'twentyfourteen' ), __( '1 Comment', 'twentyfourteen' ), __( '% Comments', 'twentyfourteen' ) ); ?></span>
            <?php
                endif;

                edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyfourteen' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' );
            ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <?php if ( is_search() ) : ?>
    <div class="entry-summary">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <?php else : ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php
            the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyfourteen' ) );
            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before'      => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyfourteen' ) . '</span>',
                'after'       => '</div>',
                'link_before' => '<span>',
                'link_after'  => '</span>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php the_tags( '<footer class="entry-meta"><span class="tag-links">', '', '</span></footer>' ); ?>
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's at least 2 ways to do this and all changes should be made in a [`child theme`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

**Note:** Use the 2nd method if using Post Formats.

**1.** In the content.php file around Line 14 change this line

```
<?php twentyfourteen_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

To this:

```
<?php if ( ! is_home() ) twentyfourteen_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

**2.** Or around line 172 of the twentyfourteen > inc > template-tags.php file you could add the is_home() [`conditional tag`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) so its like this:

```
function twentyfourteen_post_thumbnail() {
    if ( post_password_required() || is_attachment() || is_home() || ! has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        return;
    }
```

Use conditional tags to remove the featured image from other archives

[Source](http://wpsites.net/wordpress-themes/twenty-fourteen-2-ways-to-remove-featured-images-from-home-page/)

Comment: i updated my question. still doesn't work.

Comment: I tested this solution and it works for me. Maybe clear any plugin, server or browser caching.

Comment: if i do only second way. is it works for me?

Comment: See my updated answer. There's seperate files for each post format content.php